# How to stop Emacs from rendering junk characters in shell?

Tags: emacs

In my emacs shell, I see this output:

```
^[[J~% echo $PS1    
%2c%%
```

On my other machine, this stuff doesn't show up at all. Can anyone suggest a reason why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It's related to your PS1 setting. Basically Emacs will not accept TOO fancy settings of PS1. I used the following code in ~/.bashrc to distinguish PS1 between xterm and other term simulators such as Emacs. You can give it a try.

```
case $TERM in
xterm)
export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \W\a\]\[\e[31;1m\]\w\n\[\e[0m\]'
;;
*)
export PS1='\[\e[31;1m\]\w\n\[\e[0m\]'
;;
esac
```

Comment: If you're using `M-x shell` then see also `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh` as described by `C-h f shell`